# Username & Password Implementation

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a login window that I have coded in Python and I would like for the user to enter a username and password into this form in order to bring up the main window. What is the best way to implement this functionality?

I am not sure how to go about it. I am using PyQt5. Here is my Login class. I want the main class to appear as soon as the correct username and password has been entered into the login form. I have made an attempt at this but I cannot seem to get it to work.

Login Class

```
    # Import Statements
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from MainGuiWindow import Ui_MainWindow

# Main Class that holds User Interface Objects
class Ui_loginWindow(object):

    # Function for Opening Main GUI window from login window by clicking login button
    def openMainWindow(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        loginWindow.hide()
        self.window.show()

    def setupUi(self, loginWindow):
        loginWindow.setObjectName("loginWindow")
        loginWindow.setFixedSize(393, 183)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(loginWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        # username label
        self.usernameLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.usernameLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 84, 19))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.usernameLabel.setFont(font)
        self.usernameLabel.setObjectName("usernameLabel")

        # password label
        self.passwordLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.passwordLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 70, 83, 19))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.passwordLabel.setFont(font)
        self.passwordLabel.setObjectName("passwordLabel")

        # login button
        self.loginButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.loginButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 110, 101, 27))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.loginButton.setFont(font)
        self.loginButton.setObjectName("loginButton")

        # username TF
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 20, 141, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("usernameTF")

        # passwordTF
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 70, 141, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("passwordTF")
        loginWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(loginWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 393, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        loginWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(loginWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        loginWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(loginWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(loginWindow)

    # Function that sets the text on all the UI Buttons
    def retranslateUi(self, loginWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        loginWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("loginWindow", "Android SQLite DB Parser Login"))
        self.usernameLabel.setText(_translate("loginWindow", "Username:"))
        self.passwordLabel.setText(_translate("loginWindow", "Password:"))
        self.loginButton.setText(_translate("loginWindow", "Login"))

    # login functionality to login to MainGUuiWindow
    username = "admin"
    password = "password"
    def doLogin(self):
            username = str(self.ui.lineEdit.text())
            password = str(self.ui.lineEdit2.text())
            if username == "admin" and password == "password":
                self.loginButton.clicked.connect(self.openMainWindow)
            else:
                QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(self,"Bad username or password", QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok)


    # Event Handling Code Section

        # Event Handling to open Main GUI Window
            self.loginButton.clicked.connect(self.openMainWindow)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    loginWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_loginWindow()
    ui.setupUi(loginWindow)
    loginWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: There's a small mountain of code here and no actual problem to solve as far as I can tell, just a wish list of things you'd like to have happen.

Comment: I have tried to implement it but Its not correct. The attempt is in the edited code above.

Answer (score 0):

We can't write a complete code for you, but you can do like this. Try to implement in this way. This might not be the best way to implement, but this will solve your purpose.

```
# main class import statement. 

class mainwindow()  
    def __init__():
    # do your main class activity.

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    loginObj = login.login()  # login class object import it into your main class code
    loginObj.setModal(True)  # Model window, use model window, "QDialog"
    if not loginObj.succ_login_flag:  # set this flag TRUE after success login attempt
        sys.exit(0)  # exit main class

    MainWindow = mainWindow()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```